C inserting multiple strings into character array method cons
I recently came across an interview question that asked me the following:
There is a char array of 100 length, the first 25 of which are filled as follows:
xxxxAxxxxxBxxxxxxCxxxxxxx
I needed to replace the A, B, C with the following strings:

Tiger
position: 4
length: 5

Lion
position: 10
length: 4

Elephant
position: 17
length: 8

I couldn't destroy the x's to replace them with my letters, but the A, B, C needed to be replaced with the words. They didn't ask for the specifics, just for me to explain how I would do it. My answer was to first replace C with Elephant by shifting the x's, then adding "lephant", then replacing the C with an E. Then I did the same with Lion and Tiger. This way, I could skip the arithmetic caused by going from A to B and changing the position of the B and C from the already given positions of 10 and 17. My question is this: When asked about the pros and cons of going backwards to forwards over going forwards to backwards, I couldn't come up with a single con. What are the cons of going backwards over going forwards, if any?
I was told that even if this model scaled, I would be given the position and lengths of the new words, so nothing about having variable word count or sizes affects going backwards.

If you go back to front, then you'll have to shift the replaced strings too, i.e. more work.

On the other hand, the positions of the placements stay constant if you start replacing from the back. That may be interesting if you are indeed given an array of positions.

The main issue with proceeding the way you describe is that many of the xs are moved multiple times.  If there were a lot of replacements to perform then some of the xs would be moved a lot of times, which is likely what the interviewer was thinking about with regard to scaling.
That's not an issue with going backwards in general, however, just with the particular backwards methodology you described.  You have traded performance for a modest reduction in code complexity.
Secondarily, your approach has you moving most of the replacement strings, too, as a comment and another answer note.  That also makes your approach more expensive (and compounds with the previous issue).  And that also is an issue with your particular backwards approach, not an inherent issue with going backwards in general.
If you must do the replacement in-place then progressing backwards is the only sane way to shift the xs, but you should do the computations necessary to move each byte all the way to its final position in one go.  Especially so when you only have to describe your approach, not write the actual code.  It's more complex, but not prohibitively so.
If you do not have to do the replacement in-place, however, then you can achieve a compromise between performance and code complexity by writing the whole replacement, piece by piece forwards, to temporary storage, then (if necessary) copying the whole result over the original.  That might even prove faster under some circumstances -- especially if the output is not supposed to replace the input in the first place.

This is an interesting interview question -- it can have a couple of answers, but the best answer (assuming you're looking for efficiency and scalability) would involve only shifting the strings once.
Based on the positions of the inserted strings, you know that there are 4 x's before A, 5 between A and B, 6 between B and C, and 7 following C (ok, you'd have to do a strlen for the last one).
So a simple solution would be to simply to start at position 4 write Tiger followed by five x's, then Lion followed by six x's, and finally Elephant followed by seven x's.
A follow up question might be if the x's represented some unknown characters that needed to be preserved, how would you do it.   In this case you would figure out the final resting place of each of the x strings, and then copy them (from back to front so as to not overwrite any string before copying it) to the proper position, and then insert your animal names in their final resting places.

The question says "I couldn't destroy the x's to replace them with my letters", which I take to rule out your simple solution.  I imagine it's meant to model a problem where the xs represent arbitrary data, as you discuss at the end.

One other consideration -- in this case Tiger happens to longer than the string of x's following A, but if say you used Ape, then shifting that first set of x's over three would overwrite the last two x's in that string... so you would would have to iterate backwards over the characters to prevent overwriting the first character....   This of course means you couldn't use optimizations where you copy int's over rather than chars...

If you go back to front you will have more data to copy/move on each loop iteration. Front to back you have less work to do on each iteration.
For a small sample size, the difference is likely negligible. However, you generally won't be hired to work on small academic exercise type datasets.

You can code your response in both ways and put a counter to see how many moves your counter does to go from a place to another and to change letters.
On the problem : wouldn't it be faster to declare another char[100] and fill it as we go through the first char array ?
And then either return it, or change the first char address to the second ?

No other arrays were allowed. It was a firmware interview so the goal was as fast and efficient as possible.

@Malibu If this was firmware you'd definitely implement it as a double-buffered approach. Not only because creating a new string is so much faster, but also because strings are user data to go on some display or whatever, so you'll need double-buffering for that reason alone. Or else you might not be able to show anything while updating the data, which would be plain tacky.

@Malibu Anyone who has actually worked with firmware development in the real world would know this. You'd keep one copy of the data in some DMA buffer or otherwise some mirror buffer to be byte-banged over SPI etc to your display. I suspect those who held the interview were either rookies or HR people.

Doing this in-place doesn't really make sense. Candidates and interviewers who start to mumble about "Big O" going backwards or forwards, are probably not very experienced C programmers. Engineering starts with questioning the specification to begin with, whereas blindly following it is known as "code monkeying".
An interesting candidate for the job would therefore point out that moving data around is slow. Reallocating memory is slow. Iterating across the same data multiple times or copying it multiple times is slow. The conclusion ought to be: if performance matters, then simply forget about doing this in-place.
Instead:

Write down all your input data into an array of structs.

You know in advance how much data there is in the existing string, or can find out fairly quickly by doing a strlen call from the last item's position (elephant) and then add the length on the last substring together with that last item position, to get the total string length of the existing string.
Basically strlen( &str[ elephant_pos ] ) + elephant_pos.

Allocate a new string which is the old string length + the sum of all lengths, which you know in advance. +1 for the null terminator.

Build up the new string using strcat and/or memcpy by first taking a chunk of old data, then appending the new data, over and over in a loop.

Delete the old string if needed.


